# Environment variables in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, environment

I am able to run a sample hadoop program from the command prompt and am trying to run the same program from Eclipse, so that I can debug it and understand it better.

For the command line program, some environment variables are set in the `.bashrc` and the same are being read as `System.getenv().get("HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME")` in the hadoop program. But, when I am running a java program with `System.getenv().get("HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME")`, from Eclipse I am getting null.

I tried passing `-DHADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=test` to VM parameters in the runtime configurations from Eclipse, but still getting null in the standalone program. How to make the environment variables visible within Eclipse? When I iterate through `System.getenv()` in Eclipse, I see lot of variables like `DISPLAY`, `USER`, `HOME` and others. Where are they set? I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The .bashrc file is used for setting variables used by interactive login shells. If you want those environment variables available in Eclipse you need to put them in /etc/environment.

Comment: Thanks - it works - just had to reboot the machine - any way to avoid a reboot.

Comment: You can try `source /etc/environment`, but it's not garaunteed to replace environment variables in processes that are already running. Reboot is the safest bet.

Comment: Is there a equivalent in Mac Os X?

Comment: @ChandraMohan - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588442/680925) for the best method to set environment variables for Mac OSX apps.

Comment: In linux it's enough to restart the greeter (gdm, lxdm, xdm, kdm, etc). Restart the greeter from outside Xorg, open a console (for example using CTRL+ALT+F2), login and restart the greeter service. Then go back to the Xorg session with (CTRL+ALT+F1), can be another F key on your system just try everyone of them.

Answer (score 136):

You can also define an environment variable that is visible only within Eclipse.

Go to Run -> Run Configurations... and Select tab "Environment".

[image]

There you can add several environment variables that will be specific to your application.

Comment: Max, this is applicable only for the current running Program. If you are running tests or other programs, each of those has to have the environment variable set again.

Comment: You *can* do this, but probably shouldn't. It risks the environment variable's value being later changed in the OS or in Eclipse, such that the two end up contradicting each other.

Comment: This is the best way to do it imho, as it allows you to give each app your are developing on it's own config, instead of having to change your global environment each time.

Comment: Very helpful.  I like this way.

Comment: But if you want to run unit tests individually, you have to set this for each test individually, which can become annoying. How does one set that for all run configurations globally?

Comment: But my problem is that environment variables from this tab are not being picked up

Comment: Couldn't find a way to use these variables in external bash script on Ubuntu. The script being called via "Run external tool" button.  

`JLinkGDBServerCLExe -if swd -speed 4000 -device "1986BE4" -singlerun
x-terminal-emulator -e gdb-multiarch -x "$SCRIPT_DIR"` 

SCRIPT_DIR is picked up on Windows with no problem, being used in external bin file 

`start JLinkGDBServerCL.exe -if swd -speed 4000 -device "1986BE4" -singlerun
start arm-none-eabi-gdb -x "%SCRIPT_DIR%gdbscript.txt%"`

Answer (score 43):

I've created an eclipse plugin for this, because I had the same problem.
Feel free to download it and contribute to it.

It's still in early development, but it does its job already for me.

https://github.com/JorisAerts/Eclipse-Environment-Variables

[image]

Comment: This worked extremely well. I was fighting with a bad install of osx and unable to reinstall at this time but this plugin circumvented the problem.

Comment: This is such a useful plugin, you should do some finishing touch and publish it in the eclipse marketplace.

Comment: Thank you for the plugin! Works on STS 3.9.1 (Eclipse 4.7.1a)

Comment: Super! This really works & removed my long term headache. Thank you!

Comment: Totally agree with other commenters: publish!

Comment: I've pusblished it: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/environment-variables-preference-page

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: There is a bug with Eclipse 4.10. I can install the plugin but could not open environment variables tab. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 7):

You can set the Hadoop home directory by sending a -Dhadoop.home.dir to the VM. To send this parameters to all your application that you execute inside eclipse, you can set them in Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs-> (select your JRE installation) -> Edit.. -> (set the value in the "Default VM arguments:" textbox). You can replace ${HADOOP_HOME} with the path to your Hadoop installation.

[image: Select the JRE you use for running programs in Eclipse]

[image: Sending the value for hadoop.home.dir property as a VM argument]

Comment: The previous solution did work for me and shows up in getenv() results.  The JRE Default VM arguments does not work.  I tried on Mac OS X 10.8 using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: @Dorrin To access VM arguments, you have to use System.getProperty().  geetenv is for OS level variables.

Comment: I was looking for a "global" solution to setting environment variable at one place for all applications running within Eclipse. This helped. +1

Answer (score 6):

You can also start eclipse within a shell.

You export the enronment, before calling eclipse.

*Example* :

```
#!/bin/bash
export MY_VAR="ADCA"
export PATH="/home/lala/bin;$PATH"
$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse -data $YOUR_WORK_SPACE_PATH
```

Then you can have multiple instances on eclipse with their own custome environment including workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to achieve this but in the context of a MAVEN build. As part of my `pom.xml` configuration, I had a reference to an environment variable as part of a path to a local JAR:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>the group id</groupId>
  <artifactId>the artifact id</artifactId>
  <version>the version</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE}/the_local_jar_archive.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

To compile my project, I had to define the environment variable as part of the run configuration for the maven build as explained by Max's answer. I was able to launch the maven compilation and the project would compile just fine.

**However**, as this environment variable involves some dependencies, the default "problems" view of Eclipse (where compilation errors/warnings usually show) would still show errors along the lines of `Could not find artifact` and `systemPath should be an absolute path but is ${env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE}/the_local_jar_archive.jar`.

**How I fixed it**

Go into `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Worksapce -> Linked Resources` and define a new path variable.

[image: image capture of the Eclipse Preferences window]

Finally, in my case I just needed to Right click on my `pom.xml` file, select `Maven -> Update Project` and the errors disappeared from the "Problems" view.

Answer (score 0):

For the people who want to override the **Environment Variable** of OS in Eclipse project, refer to @MAX answer too.

It's useful when you have release project end eclipse project at the same machine.

The release project can use the OS Environment Variable for test usage and eclipse project can override it for development usage.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the env. variables by sourcing (source command inside the shell (ksh) scirpt) the file that was settign them.
Then I called the .ksh script from the external Tools