# \Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, java-6

Whenever I am starting my ***WebLogic*** server I am getting this error msg in my eclipse console:

> \Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin was unexpected at this time.

My m/c is a 64bit one.

Comment: Please post full error message, this maybe because your java_home is not set

Answer (score 30):

In case if someone encountered this question now, like I just did, If you are using 32 bit Java on a 64 bit machine, you can use following way to set JAVA_HOME to get rid of space issue in class path. No need to provide quotes.

C:\progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_67

progra~2 refers to Program Files(x86).

Comment: Awesome!! this should be accepted as the right answer!

Comment: Randomly got the error across some batch files with your exact scenario. I have quoted path but for some reason the batches didn't like it. Works like charm with that method.

Answer (score 8):

Check your path variables. The most common cause of it is forgetting quotes.

Your ***%JAVA_HOME%*** could be set to path like this:

`C:\program files(x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_03`

and ***spaces*** in such a path are not resolved until put into ***double quotes***:

`"C:\program files(x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_03"`

Comment: I went to Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings and added the double quotes but still getting the same error

Comment: you might be overriding this variable by eclipse

Comment: how can i stop eclipse from overriding this variable

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse

Comment: I started startWeblogic.cmd from console and got the same error

Comment: Solution to a similar problem: Did you run configure.cmd after unzip wls1211_dev.zip to setup JAVA_HOME and MW_HOME? The cmd file is located at the root directory of the installation

Comment: there is no such file in my root directory

Comment: Don't forget about MSDOS short filename convention as they sometimes can bite you; you might try: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_03.

Answer (score 1):

Shantanu,

You are getting this problem because you have a misconfigured value in your path environment variable.

Go to  Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings
select Environment Variables
1) Make sure that the value for "path" in user variables is correct.
2) Make sure that the value for "path" in System variables is correct.
3) Check to see if there's a classpath Variable defined in user/system variables and make sure its correct too.

I remember when installing MKS toolkit I think, it appended the path variable with its own  JDK location. I removed it all together and got rid of this error.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Sridhar.Could you please explain what should my path variable be set to?

Comment: You can either not have any path variable in your windows environment configuration, or set it to something that's real and exists in your system. In my case the path was pointing to a non existing directory. I removed it all together and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Java version, this error we can see because of 32 or 64 bit java version.

**Example :**

You have downloaded software version working on Java 32 but you have already installed Java 64.

Answer (score 0):

There may be \Java\jdk1.6.0_03\ installed on your machine and conflicting with JDK of WLServer. Uninstall and run the server will resolve the issue.