# Setting environment variables for an entire project

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables

In Eclipse, it is possible to set environment variables using "run configurations", but this works only for a specific main program.

I have many different main programs in the same project, and I want to set the same environment variables in all of them. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I created a plugin for that. Check my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37604209/5831548

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do for a global environment variable is usually set it at the OS level. I do not know if there is a way in Eclipse to set global environment variables.

Comment: How exactly do you do this at the OS level? I put some environment variables in "/etc/environment", rebooted my computer, verified that the variables exist (in a shell), but, in Eclipse they were not found...

Comment: This depends on the OS. In linux, that would usually be the `/etc/environment`. There is a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse. Hope that answers your question. However, I have a feeling that you are using a Mac. So this other post may be more relevant (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/588442#588442)

Answer (score 2):

You can create and set variables globally in Eclipse via the String Substitution form. The form is found via `Preferences->Run/Debug->String Substitution`.

Variables declared in the form can be used by referencing them with `${variable_name}`.

More information about string substitution can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-string_substitution.htm)

Comment: OK, but I still have to set the variables to ${variable_name} for every main program separately?

Comment: Yes, for every program/run configuration you will have to set the environment variables so that they use the variables from the string substitution form. By having a setup like that, it is easy to change a variable value and let all run configurations use that change without updating them.