# Scala: Eclipse access to environment variables in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, scala, ubuntu, environment-variables

I was trying to access environment variables in an Eclipse Scala Worksheet and it wouldn't work.

Initially it was because my variable was defined in `.bashrc` and that is not good, since `.bashrc` is only for login shells and not GUI applications. I changed the variables to `.profile`, sourced the file and reloaded my session (logging out and logging in, just in case). After that I could access the variables in a normal Scala script (in Eclipse) but still couldn't in the worksheet. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

**testworksheet.sc**

```
object testworksheet {
    val key = sys.env("my_key")
    // Result in a NoSuchElementException in the worksheet,
    // though works in a script.
}
```

**~/.profile**

```
export my_key=my_value
```

Comment: To increase the chance of getting a relevant answer, please consider providing an appropriate example code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Updated the question, though there is not much to it since I believe it is more of a configuration problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `.profile` is also for setting up variables for your interactive shell, which passes those variables along to a script since this shell is what you run the script from.

If you want to pass variables to eclipse you have to [make them system-wide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables), i.e. to put them in `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile.d`. See some doc [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html).

In a completely different approach, you can also [set application-specific variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12810433/47978) for your application.