# envirnoment variable set on terminal but System.getenv returns null. java problems

Tags: java, path, set, environment-variables

I've changed my `~/.bashrc` file. I've changed `/etc/environment`. I've done `export WNHOME="/usr/local/WordNet-3.0"`. I tried everything [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-do-i-set-a-user-environment-variable-permanently-not-session) and more. (I'm running arch linux, in case that's of any consequence).

I think the environment variable must be set on my machine, if I check it with `echo $WNHOME` I get the correct result.

However when I call `System.out.println(System.getenv("WNHOME"));` in my java program I keep getting `null`, what could be the reason for this?

The output looks like this:

```
Path is 'null/dict'
null
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Dictionary directory does not exist: null/dict
at edu.mit.jwi.data.FileProvider.open(FileProvider.java:306)
at edu.mit.jwi.DataSourceDictionary.open(DataSourceDictionary.java:92)
at edu.mit.jwi.CachingDictionary.open(CachingDictionary.java:133)
at MITJavaWordNetInterface.main(MITJavaWordNetInterface.java:30)
```

The code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory
    String wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
    String path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
    System.out.println("Path is '" + path + "'"); 

    URL url = new URL ("file", null , path );
    System.out.println(System.getenv("WNHOME"));
    //final URL url = Paths.get(wnhome, "dict").toUri().toURL();

    // construct the dictionary object and open it
    IDictionary dict = new Dictionary ( url ) ;
    dict . open () ;

    // look up first sense of the word "dog "
    IIndexWord idxWord = dict . getIndexWord ("dog", POS . NOUN ) ;
    IWordID wordID = idxWord . getWordIDs () . get (0) ;
    IWord word = dict . getWord ( wordID ) ;
    System . out . println ("Id = " + wordID ) ;
    System . out . println (" Lemma = " + word . getLemma () ) ;
    System . out . println (" Gloss = " + word . getSynset () . getGloss () ) ;      
}
```

Comment: Is this variable set in the environment you run the Java program in?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: How do you run the Java program? Do you run it from a shell where `WNHOME` is set?

Comment: I've been running it from eclipse, which i don't run from a terminal i run it using this 'wildcard key' + 'r' and then run it like that

Comment: Genius! i can run it from the terminal. which is a nice hack but.. sort of ... unsatisfying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the environment variable in `~/.profile` file

If we set the environment variable in `~/.bashrc` then those variable are accessable only to the application started from shell. For desktop application to access the environment variable set it into `~/.profile` file.

Comment: still doesn't work. java shows it as null. it's in eclipse. but i 'cleaned' the projects, and tried and still no.

Comment: Try after restarting the eclipse.

Comment: have you sourced the .profile after making changes? After making changes in .profile use `source ~/.profile`

Comment: yeah, did that. still nothing

Comment: @LutzHorn running it from the shell where i set the env varaible is a good idea, that works, but if i try it with my run command it doesn't, which is annying but... anyway, that's good enough to get the job done. thank you.

Comment: Try this for setting env only for eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12810433/1642005