# Python: can't access newly defined environment variables

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I can't access my env var:

```
import subprocess, os
print os.environ.get('PATH') # Works well
print os.environ.get('BONSAI') # doesn't work
```

But the env var is well added in my `/home/me/.bashrc`:

```
BONSAI=/home/me/Utils/bonsai_v3.2
export BONSAI
```

And I can access this env var from a new terminal.

Comment: If `os.environ` doesn't have the value, then in **that** parent environment there is no such shell variable.

Comment: What does `echo $BONSAI` say before you execute your Python program?

Comment: It say "/home/me/Utils/bonsai_v3.2" like I want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After updating your `.bashrc`, perform `source ~/.bashrc` to apply the changes.

Also, merge the two `BONSAI`-related calls into one:

```
export BONSAI=/home/me/Utils/bonsai_v3.2
```

---

*UPDATE: It was actually an attempt to update the environment for some Eclipse-based IDE. This is a different usecase altogether. It should be described in the Eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm). Also, a similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse).*

Comment: I added export BONSAI=/home/me/Utils/bonsai_v3.2 in /etc/profile also and perform a source /etc/profile but it still does'nt work

Comment: Try the one-liner: `export BONSAI=/home/me/Utils/bonsai_v3.2; python <script-name>`. What is the result?

Comment: It works but I want to use eclipse... so I need to access to the env var anywhere...

Comment: Have you restarted your eclipse IDE after updating the `.bashrc` or the `/etc/profile` ? Are you sure your eclipse IDE inherits the environment specified in `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Yes but maybe I must restart the computer, I try

Comment: You should check how new environment variables are added to the Eclipse IDE. Maybe [this](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm) can help.