# Python script can't access some environment variables

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, containers

I am building Docker Image `FROM node:8.9.3-alpine` (which is Debian) and then running it as usual and passing parameters like this:

```
docker run -dt \
-e lsRegion=${bamboo_lsRegion} \
-e lsCluster=${bamboo_lsCluster} \
```

Then inside that container I am exporting some variables and when I echo them, I can see proper value

```
export lsEnv=${lsEnv:-'dev'}
```

Later in scripts I run python script and when I run the `print(os.environ)` I can see all the variables from `docker run` like `lsRegion` but I do not see the newly exported one like `lsEnv`.

I already found and tried to solve with this: [Python: can't access newly defined environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981780/python-cant-access-newly-defined-environment-variables) by calling the `source ~/.bashrc` but I cannot find that file.

I have tried

```
~/.bashrc
/etc/bash.bashrc
/root/.bashrc
```

But neither of those exist (also does not know if this solve my problem) and it ends with this error message `/app/deploy.sh: source: line 16: can't open '/root/.bashrc'`

---

More reproducible example:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.9.3-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    python \
    py-pip \
    ca-certificates \
    openssl \
    groff \
    less \
    bash \
    curl \
    jq \
    git \
    zip \
    build-base \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip awscli \
  && aws configure set preview.cloudfront true

ENV TERRAFORM_VERSION 0.11.10

RUN wget -O terraform.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip terraform.zip -d /usr/local/bin && \
    rm -f terraform.zip

RUN apk -v --update add python py-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade awscli
RUN pip install --upgrade boto3

COPY ./build.variables /app/build.variables
COPY ./aws/taskdef/template.json /app/template.json
COPY ./deploy.sh /app/deploy.sh
COPY ./deploy.py /app/deploy.py
COPY ./terraform /app/terraform

CMD ["sh", "/app/deploy.sh"]
```

deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -x

cd /app/terraform
./run-terraform.sh
cd ..
python /app/deploy.py
```

terraform/run-terraform.sh

```
   ...
   export lsEnv="NotThere"
   ...
```

python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
print(os.environ)
```

The print will show `lsRegion` or `lsCluster` but it will not show the `lsEnv`

Comment: Create a `~/.bashrc ` file yourself and add your exports to it. Then source this file.

Comment: @max And if I dont have it, what happens with exported variables? They are just living in a memory?

Comment: If `.bashrc` contains calls to `export`, then sourcing it does the same thing as running the same `export` commands manually.

Comment: How *exactly* do you start the container, run the `export` command, and run the Python script. It sounds like you aren't starting the Python script from the environment you think you are.

Comment: You probably call the Python script from another context than where you exported the variables. So adding them to `~/.bashrc` should fix that.

Comment: Can you share your whole Dockerfile?  Why/how are you running a Python script in a Node-based image?

Comment: @chepner - add more info

Comment: @DavidMaze - added more info

Comment: @max - added more info

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Docker. You are *executing* `run-terraform.sh`, not sourcing it, so your definition of `lsEnv` disappears as soon as `run-terraform.sh` exits.

Comment: @chepner - ah, thanks, and how do I "source" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `deploy.sh`, you need to source `run-terraform.sh` if you want to affect the environment of the process that runs `deploy.py`, rather than the environment created for the process that runs `run-terraform.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

cd /app/terraform
source ./run-terraform.sh
cd ..
python /app/deploy.py
```

(You could also use `. ./run-terraform.sh`; `source` is a more readable `bash` synonym for the POSIX `.` command, but `.` is necessary if you are using some other POSIX-compliant shell that doesn't support `source`.)

Comment: I have encounter another problem. When I do this, it fails with `./run-terraform.sh: line 41: syntax error: bad substitution` which is `terraform apply -var "environment=$lsSpecificEnv" -var "environment_vpc=${lsEnv^}" -var "region=$lsRegion" -var "service=$SERVICE_NAME" -var "path_pattern=/v*/$SERVICE_NAME" -auto-approve`. I dont understand whats going on as both files (deploy and run-terraform) starts with `#!/bin/bash -x` anyway. Does `source` change the execution?

Comment: I can confirm that this `${lsEnv^}` does work without `source` when running the script and when I run it with `source` it stops working with that error

Comment: You are either using an older version (pre-4.0) version of `bash`, or more likely `sh` does not refer to `bash` in Alpine Linux, but some other POSIX shell that doesn't support `${...^}` syntax. (In that case, `source` itself probably won't work, but the shell doesn't get as far as trying to run the `source` command before the parameter expansion fails.)

Comment: With `CMD ["sh", "/app/deploy.sh"]`, the shebang is irrelevant; `sh` is used to run the script, ignoring the shebang.

Comment: actually I used source and it works (look to my answer), when I dont use source the line is executed properly, but if its behind source, it does not. Really weird. However I solve it with `CMD ["bash", "/app/deploy.sh"]` thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by calling this command in `terraform/run-terraform.sh` for each environment variable I will need in python script:

```
echo "export lsTargetGroup=$lsTargetGroup" >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then in `deploy.sh` I just add `source ~/.bashrc` before calling python script