# Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path

Tags: java, c#, android, appium

I Create a Sample for lunch whatsapp with appium and C# .NET

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
            DesiredCapabilities capabilites = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilites.SetCapability("deviceName", "Google Nexus 5 - 5.0.0 - API 21 - 1080x1920");
            capabilites.SetCapability("platformversion", "5.1.0");
            capabilites.SetCapability("platformname", "Android");
            capabilites.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.whatsapp");
            capabilites.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.whatsapp.Main");
            driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilites);
            //com.whatsapp:id/registration_phone
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("com.whatsapp:id/registration_phone"));
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            driver.Quit();
        }
```

I start appium, I can get my device and I can see my device in ui automator viewer .

[image: http://i.cubeupload.com/vWTznm.png]

But when I Run My Program I get this Error on this Line :

[image: http://i.cubeupload.com/ENGYvU.png]

and I set PATH and ANDROID_PATH :
ANDROID_PATH : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
PATH : %PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
all of them are correct and true

I guess this problem becuse i have more than one SDK
1. for android studio : C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
2. for eclipse : C:\android\sdk\android

How I can chose a specific SDK location for my C# program .

Answer (score 2):

you can also go into Eclipse --> Run Menu--> Run Confiuguration -->Environment Tab--> ANDROID_HOME --> Give Path to the SDK folder

Also as other suggested set your path variable. Taken from [https://www.java.com](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)/en/download/help/path.xml

> Windows Windows 10 and Windows 8
>
> ```
> In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
> Click the Advanced system settings link.
> Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH
> ```
>
> environment variable does not exist, click New.
>       In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close
>   all remaining windows by clicking OK.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> Windows 7
>
> ```
> From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
> Choose Properties from the context menu.
> Click the Advanced system settings link.
> Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH
> ```
>
> environment variable does not exist, click New.
>       In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close
>   all remaining windows by clicking OK.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> Windows Vista
>
> ```
> From the desktop, right click the My Computer icon.
> Choose Properties from the context menu.
> Click the Advanced tab (Advanced system settings link in Vista).
> Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH
> ```
>
> environment variable does not exist, click New.
>       In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close
>   all remaining windows by clicking OK.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> Windows XP
>
> ```
> Select Start, select Control Panel. double click System, and select the Advanced tab.
> Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH
> ```
>
> environment variable does not exist, click New.
>       In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close
>   all remaining windows by clicking OK.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

Comment: Cool tip for n00bs like me: if you change your path and/or environment variables in your system, you need to shut down and restart Intellij (or I guess any IDE) so that it reloads the new path. Yay it may sound obvious, but it would have saved me 5 minutes of WTF.

Answer (score 1):

SET Environment variables in Eclipse(IDE) locally with ANDROID_HOME and then try to run...it worked fine for me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Good answer. The user may not be familiar with how to set environment variables in Eclipse.  A more complete answer would point to more information such as the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048216/environment-variables-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

You can write BAT file for starting appium process. Inside of this batch file write SET ANDROID_HOME = blabla, it will override system variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check if system32 is present as path variable