# Environment variables tab missing from run configurations in eclipse with cucumber plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber, gherkin

Have a Java/Maven project with Cucumber which reads an environment variable using System.getenv("VARNAME")

Using the latest eclipse I installed the cucumber plugin but when trying to run a single feature file, I don't seem to be able to set the environment variable as the Environment tab is missing from the run/debug configurations (see the screenshot below).

I can think of multiple workarounds, but wanted to make sure first that I am not missing something obvious.

[image]

Comment: is it remote app?

Comment: The project is local. Running off of my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with installing plugin **Eclipse-Environment-Variables**

1. go to Help->Eclipse Marketplace

[image]

2)searching for Eclipse-Environment-Variables  and installing it

[image]

3)going to Tab Windows ->preference

[image]

4. searching for environment  variables and adding them

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37604209/2347210